# bash shell field needs to be greater than #

Tags: linux, bash

I am having problems with how to do something.  I need to take the output of a few piped scripts in sequence of a data file with comma separated fields.  In the end, I need to get awk to take the data in the 7th field, find values over 31 and print it out.  This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

selection='31'

if [ ! $# -lt 1 ]; then
selection=$1
fi


while read y; do

hwy=$(echo $y | awk -F':'  '{print $7 }')

if [ "$hwy" -g "$selection" ]; then
    echo $y
fi
done
```

I have written this so you can run the script and change the # to another # if you want to.

After it has retrieved this info from the parsed data file, I need to print out a header that I type up (simple echo command), print the header after 20 lines of data with a empty line of the output (don't know how to do that) and then on the last line of the output, print out the # of records processed (simple wc -l).

What do I need to do to get the greater than 31 to be parsed from the $7 field?  How do I do the header every 20 lines with a empty line before printing another header?

```
echo   Year      Make     Model    Cylinders     Engine Displacement   City   Hwy
```

and the the above report.  And if there is more 20 of the output. it would put a new header in.

How do I do that?

Comment: How about adding a header to every 20 lines with an empty line for the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `-gt` instead of `-g`:

```
if [ "$hwy" -gt "$selection" ]; then
              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are comma separated, you should tell `awk` to use a comma as the separator.

You can do the whole thing with just `awk` and without clumsy `echo` commands in a loop:

```
selection=${1:-31}
awk -F, -v selection=$selection '{ if ($7 > selection) print $7 }'
```

Other than a shebang line (`#!/bin/sh` or similar), that's all it takes.  The `${1:-31}` notation is an example of [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).